# Searching for keywords prefixed with underscores does not behave as expected

Tags: support, status-completed, search

I am looking for a Microsoft C++ language extension, the `__try` keyword for exception handling.

On StackOverflow, the results show anything that matches `try`. This is not what I want.

I'd like to know if there is a workaround to not get false positives for `try` when I am looking for `__try`.

`__except` also fails to get the expected results.

Comment: Maybe you should __try harder?

Comment: That's funny.  I really don't want to be using the SEH stuff, but this is out of my hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works now, but you must put the term in quotes.

> "__try"

Comment: Thanks.  that was not obvious - I suppose I would have tried that if there was whitespace in the string, but underscores muse be treated specially for SO.