# Searching for C & C++ identifiers like __FILE__, __func__, etc

Tags: support, status-completed, search

I was looking for some information on SO about the C & C++ `__func__` identifier, so I searched for: `[c++] __func__`.  Only 3 of the first 50 results showed the full `__func__` search term; all the others simply had "func" in the text, so I looked for a way to improve my search terms.

Some digging on here suggested that I should [put the search term in quotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13826/) or escape the underscores with `%5F`, both of which give exactly the same results.  (Though I did find a difference between searching for `[c++] "__func"` and `[c++] __func`.)  I had similar lack of success for other C & C++ identifiers like `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, `__DATE__`, etc.

What should my search terms be to show me just questions with `__func__`?

Comment: I apologize if this is a duplicate, but as you can see, I have trouble searching for these terms. :/

Comment: It seems that underscores are ignored in searches. You may be out of luck using the site's search function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[We now handle searches like this much better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange).  In this case just wrap C++ in quotes to find what you're looking for: [__func__ "c++"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=__func__+%22c%2B%2B%22)

Answer (score 2):

Google tends to do a bit better with a lot of searches.  Try a search like this on Google:

```
__func__ c++ site:stackoverflow.com
```